# How do I stop the import of a module without deleting the import statement and run a different module instead?

Tags: python

This my code in Python:

```
#This is  list of my projects
from subprocess import call
from runpy import run_module
projects=["Pyriddle","Sql#1","loop practices"]
print(projects)
select=input("select a project to run")
if select == "Pyriddle" or " Pyriddle":
    import module1
    run_module:(module1)
elif select!= "Pyriddle" or " Pyriddle": run_module:(module1)=False
if select =="Sql#1" or " Sql#1":
     import module2  
     run_module:(module2)
elif select != "Sql#1" or " Sql#1":run_module:(module2)=False
if select =="loop practices" or " loop practices":
    import module3
    run_module:(module3) 
elif select !="loop practices" or " loop practices":run_module:(module3)=False
if select =="":
        exit #replace exit and the blank quotes with the required module and lines
```

*how can I stop a module from running and run a different module instead?
I tried multiple methods such as quit() and exit() and stop_module:()
the last method doesn't work, but I think it should be a python feature.
Are there any other methods which can be used to achieve my goal?
If so please tell.*

Comment: What do you aim to do? What was the expeted input and output? What was the output when you used `quit`/ `exit` etc.

Comment: First, use `select.strip()` instead of `or` condition to account for leading spaces. Secondly, can you elaborate on what you mean by stop and run a different module? It looks like there are `if` statements already in place to run various once already.

Comment: The expected input was the file name and the out put would be the file, however it abruptly runs one file instead of the other

Comment: even with the if statements module 1 runs instead of the expected file

Comment: it has to be `if select == "Pyriddle" or select == " Pyriddle":`. Eventually `if select in ("Pyriddle", " Pyriddle"):` but I would rather use `if select.lower().strip() == "pyriddle":`

Comment: if `run_module` is a function then it should be without `:` - `run_module(module1)`.

Comment: when you use `import module` then this `module` is automatically executed - so using `run_module` is not needed. And if you want to execute it many times then inside module you should rather put code in function - ie. `def main()` - and later import it only once and execute many times `module.main()`

Comment: I don't know why use use `elif`. If you don't want to execute function then skip `elif`

Comment: @furas that is the syntax for run module and the elif is used to select the other module

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that you use `or` in wrong way.

It has to be

```
if select == "Pyriddle" or select == " Pyriddle":
```

or more readable

```
if (select == "Pyriddle") or (select == " Pyriddle"):
```

Eventually you could use `in` with `list`/`tuple`/`set` for this

```
if select in ("Pyriddle", " Pyriddle"):
```

But I would use `strip()` and `lower()` to make it even more useful

```
if select.lower().strip() == "pyriddle":
```

and this will match even if user write `PYRIDDLE`, `pyRIDDLE`, `PyRiDlE`, etc.

---

**EDIT:**

I don't know what you have in modules but `import` should automatically run code in module and it doesn't need to use `runpy`.  But `import` remeber already imported modules and it doesn't import it second time

In module I would put code in function - i.e. `def main()` - to import it (only once) without executing code and execute function manually when I need it. Eventually I would use `__name__` to execute `run()` automatically when I run module directly.

**module1.py**

```
def run():
    # my code
    print('hello module1')

# it will run function automatically when module executed directly
# but it will NOT execute function when mdoule is imported to other code
if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

**main.py**

```
# you can even import it at start (if you want to execute it many times)
# it will NOT execute `run()` automatically because it uses `__name__`
#import module1  
#import module2
#import module3

projects = ["Pyriddle", "Sql#1", "loop practices"]

while True:

    print( "\n".join(projects) )

    select = input("select a project to run (or `q` for quit)")
    select = select.lower().strip()
    
    if select == "pyriddle":
        import module1  # it will NOT execute `run()` automatically because it uses `__name__`
        module1.run()   # run function manually
    elif select == "sql#1":
        import module2  # it will NOT execute `run()` automatically because it uses `__name__`
        module2.run()   # run function manually
    elif select == "loop practices":
        import module3  # it will NOT execute `run()` automatically because it uses `__name__`
        module3.run()   # run function manually
    elif select in ("q", "quit", "exit"):
        exit() 
        #break
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that in my project